# Proving a limit with a logarithm exists

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Show that the limit of $f(x)=x\log{x}$ tends to $\infty$ as $x\to\infty$.

So given a $k>0$ I want to find $M>0$ such that $|f(x)|>k$ whenever $|x|>M$.

I am having difficulties in not knowing how to deal the logarithm. Note $$|f(x)|=|x\log{x}|=|x||\log{x}| > k$$ but I really have no idea what to compare the logarithm to. I know that I want to find a function that is less than this for a choice of values of $x$ (which may be all $x$) but I don't really know any functions which allow me to do so.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the inequality $1 < \log x$ for all large enough $x$.
Thus, $|f(x)|=|x||\log x|>|x|$.

Answer (score 0):

*So given a $k>0$ I want to find $M>0$ such that $|f(x)|>k$ whenever $|x|>M$.*

No. This would only show that

$$|f(x)| = |x\log x| \to \infty \text{ as } |x| \to\infty$$

You need to find $M>0$ such that $f(x)>k$ whenever $x>M$

Now, for $x > e$,

$$ \log x > 1 $$ therefore $$ x \log x > x$$

... as the adopted answer hints.